# Only default payment processor shows on forms

Tags: civicontribute

I have two payment processors, one for credit card and one for electronic check. When I am logged in as admin and I fill out my form I have a radio button asking if I want to pay via check or credit card. But when I am not logged in as admin I only get my default payment processor to show..I do not have the radio button asking how I want to pay. I need this to show up as it does when I am logged in as admin. Is this a permission issue? If not what would be causing this?

I am using Wordpress and CiviCRM version 5.7.2, I am also using the standard Civi contribution/payment page.

Comment: Hi - you might want to edit your question to indicate what version of Civi you're using, and what CMS... that will help people out.  Also, whether you're using a standard Civi contribution/payment page or some other form (e.g., a Drupal webform).