# Can you use multiple payment processor on one form

Tags: civicontribute, payment-processor

I want my users to be able to choose from two different payment processors. I have two payment processors set up in Civi. When I am logged in as admin and go to my donate form I see a fieldset called "Payment options" where the user has an option to choose which payment processor they want to use. (one is for credit card and one is for electronic check). Everything works as expected until I am not logged in as admin. When I am not logged in as Admin I only see the default payment processor which is the credit card. How do I get that "Payment Options"  fieldset to show for non-admin users?

I see the fieldset when I debug the page. It is called "crm-group payment-options-group" and it is set to display="None" Is there a way I can get this to display on my public forms?

I am using Wordpress, Civi 5.7.2 and I am using a Civi contribution form.

Comment: This seems like a permissions issue - you've confirmed, for example, that anonymous users have the "Make online contributions" permission enabled?

Comment: To answer the Question (title) - yes you can. So the question is more - why isn't it working for you.

Comment: oh which i see you did in  https://civicrm.stackexchange.com/questions/27591/only-default-payment-processor-shows-on-forms

Comment: I was thinking it was a permission issue as well. I checked that the Make online contributions permission was set for anonymous users. I also looked at all other contribution permissions and it seems like everything is in order. Any other ideas?

Comment: Which payment processors are you trying to use?  I _have_ seen multiple payment processors work so, as Peter said, it's definitely possible in Civi, but it would be helpful to know what specific processors you're attempting to use.

Comment: The company is BNG and I am trying to process credit card and electronic check as two separate payment processors. I don't think it is the processor itself since It works successfully when I am logged in as admin.

Comment: I am seeing console errors on the page you listed https://lab.civicrm.org/dev/wordpress/issues/15   Can you give the full CiviCRM link to the donation page?   I expect that a plugin conflict is preventing the js from loading properly

Comment: Here is the full CiviCRM link, https://aflbs.org/civicrm/?page=CiviCRM&q=civicrm/contribute/transact&reset=1&id=9. Thank you so much for looking into this!

Comment: I noticed a couple of things. I tried to add a different price set to test if using a default value would change things. When I logged in as a non-admin user, it did not show my new price set. It kept reverting to the old price set. But again when I am logged in as admin I see the new price set. I also noticed that on all my contribution forms, loged in as admin or not, the total field is not calculating. Could that be part of the issue?

Answer (score 1):

I figured out the issue. It was the Autoptimize plugin that was causing the total amount not to show. I checked the setting: "Force JavaScript in ? Load JavaScript early, this can potentially fix some JS-errors, but makes the JS render blocking."

Now that I have this checked the total box shows and I get the payment options section to show. Yay!

Comment: if you have the 'reputation' you may be able to 'accept' your own answer - which is good as it stops the ticket popping back at the top of the list all the time